# Is there a way to stop SQL*Plus exiting on Control-C?

Tags: windows, oracle, sqlplus

I'm using SQL*Plus on Windows, and keep accidentally hitting Ctrl-C, which causes SQL*Plus to exit. Is there any way to prevent this?

The best workaround I've found so far is to prepend the command with `cmd.exe /k` as suggested [here](http://yong321.freeshell.org/oranotes/SqlplusSetup.html), which at least keeps the prompt open so you can still see the previous commands and results.

Answer (score -2):

```
start /b sqlplus.exe scott/tiger @script.sql
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to run SQL*Plus interactively, rather than run a script.

Comment: I did but it still doesn't work - when I first enter my SQL commands, they are passed to the Command Prompt, which doesn't understand them. If I enter them again it works, but hitting Ctrl-C still breaks out of SQL*Plus. The documentation for 'start /b' says, 'The application has ^C handling ignored... unless the application enables ^C processing', so perhaps SQL*Plus does have ^C handling which it isn't possible to disable?